# How to Generate xml from sql for below pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm writing one stored procedure, which I have to create a xml column from db.

`µ = CHAR(181)` this is value separator,

`¶ = CHAR(182)` this is row separator

This is the statement I wrote. I know its not well formed.

```
SELECT @xmlString= CAST('<root><Section> ID =' + REPLACE(REPLACE ('20211µ1¶20212µ2', CHAR(182), 
        '</Section><Section> ID ='),CHAR(181), ' Slno=') + '</Section></root>' AS XML)
```

This is the pattern which I need to display like this.

```
<root>
        <sections id="20211" slno="1" ></sections>
        <sections id="20215" slno="2" ></sections>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @s varchar(50) = '20211µ1¶20212µ2'
declare @xmlString xml

;with C as
(
  select T.N.value('value[1]', 'int') as id,
         T.N.value('value[2]', 'int') as slno
  from (select cast('<item><value>'+replace(replace(@s, 'µ','</value><value>'), '¶','</value></item><item><value>')+'</value></item>' as xml)) as X(XMLCol)
    cross apply X.XMLCol.nodes('item') as T(N)
)
select @xmlString = 
  (
   select C.id as [@id] ,
          C.slno as [@slno]
   from C
   for xml path('sections'), root('root'), type
  )

select @xmlString
```

Result:

```
<root>
  <sections id="20211" slno="1" />
  <sections id="20212" slno="2" />
</root>
```